# Manually configure EVM Assembly Tag

Tags: solc, compilation, optimization

I have read that Ethereum during the compilation splits the code into tags.

The solc optimizer doesn’t optimize across tags. If we consider “1+1”, it can be optimized to 0x2 if under the same tag:

```
// Optimize OK!
   tag_0:
   0x1
   0x1
   add
```

But not if the instructions are separated by tags:

```
// Optimize Fail!
   tag_0:
   0x1
   0x1
   tag_1:
   add
   ...
```

Is there any way we can configure how the solc compiler tags the code?